# unlimited combination

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

It's a combination problem.
50 people shall be splitted in groups less than five $(\le5)$ what are the number of all possible combinations?

That means there can exist 1-person groups, 2-people groups, 3,4,5-people groups in one possible situation. The question is asking how many situations could there be?

Comment: Is it necessary that the groups have null intersection?

Comment: not necessarily... see the comments below

Comment: You agree that it's a problem about *partitioning* --- that means the groups don't intersect each other.

Comment: Do you have some reason to believe there's a formula, or an efficient way to compute the answer?

Comment: If they have null intersection, then I think, I may not have to think very much to get a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F(n)$ denotes the number of such partitions for $n$ total people, then
$$
F(n)=F(n-1) + (n-1)F(n-2)+\frac {1}{2!}(n-1)(n-2)F(n-3)+\frac {1}{3!}(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)F(n-4)+\frac {1}{4!}(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)F(n-5)
$$
which amounts to picking one person and explicitly putting him alone or in a group of 1,2,3,4 persons.

Of course $F(1)=1$ and $F(a<0)=0$.

I am not aware of an explicit analytic solution to this recurrence relation but a simple script should give you the answer for $n=50$

Comment: Nice idea.  But I think you should divide the $(n-1)(n-2)F(n-3)$ term, for example, by 2.

Comment: @Michael Of course I should ; ) Thank you

Comment: In the second idea, don't you miss out 4+4+2=5+5?

Comment: @Michael: Indeed, among other mistakes there is this one yes. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

$${50 \choose 5} + {50 \choose 4} + {50 \choose 3} + {50 \choose 2} + {50 \choose 1}$$

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP wants. Your answer is the number of different non-empty subgroups of the 50 people of size at most 5. The question is harder: In how many ways can a group of 50 people be _partitioned into subgroups_ where none of the subgroups contains more than 5 people.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. THANK YOU for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

From Frederic's recursion, let $F(n)=n!G(n)$, then the recursion for $G(n)$ is 
$$nG(n)=G(n-1)+\frac{G(n-2)}{2}+\frac{G(n-3)}{6}+\frac{G(n-4)}{24}$$
Let $H(x)$ be the generating function $H(x)=\sum G(n)x^n$, then 
$$H'(x)=H(x)+xH(x)/2+x^2H(x)/6+x^3H(x)/24\\
H(x)=\exp(x+x^2/4+x^3/18+x^4/96)$$
I expect the dominant term, for large $n$, will be $F(n)\approx n!/((n/4)!96^{n/4})$